# How many different group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{3Z}$ into $SL_{n}(7)$ are there?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following question:

> How many different group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{3Z}$ into $SL_{n}(7)$ are there?

I think that the answer is the number of elements of order $3$ in $SL_{n}(7)$.
For $n=1$, we have just trivial homomorphism. And for $n=2$, $|SL_{2}(7)|=336$ There must be a method to answer this question. Thanks!

Comment: if there are k elements with oreder 3 in Sl(n,7) then ,k+1 homomorphism exist.

Comment: You're right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The number of homomorphisms is actually the number of elements of order $3$ plus one, because of the trivial homomorphism.

It might be easier to do the counting in ${\rm GL}_n(7)$, and then decide how many of your conjugacy classes of elements of order $3$ have determinant $1$.

Every element of order $3$ can be diagonalized in ${\rm GL}_n(7)$, and its conjugacy class is determined by its multiset of eigenvalues, which are all equal to $1,2$ or $4$.

So the classes can be parametrized by pairs $a,b$, the multiplicities of eigenvalues $2$ and $4$, where $1 \le a+b \le n$, and the centralizer of the such an element (in ${\rm GL}_n(7)$) is isomorphic to ${\rm GL}_a(7) \times {\rm GL}_b(7) \times {\rm GL}_{n-a-b}(7)$. So you can work out the order of this class.

To get determinant $1$, you need $3|(a-b)$. It would not be too hard to calculate all this for a fixed $n$, but a general formula would be  a bit of a mess.

Why do you want to do this anyway?